# Make the Nav Menu close after clicking a link in <li> (Only on mobile)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the question is in the title.
Code (that's not working):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).resize(function() {
        windowsize = $(window).width();
          if (windowsize >= 1025) {
            $('.nav-menu> ul > li').click(function(){
              $(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function(){
            }else {

       });
      });
     });
    });
```

The `nav-menu` class is the same in both the mobile and pc version

Comment: Ouhcy.  I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).  As your code is now, another developer touches any html and your javascript breaks :(

Answer (score 1):

The code is incorrectly structured, get yourself a nice code editor that highlights your syntax so you can easily spot similar problems.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).resize(function () {

        windowsize = $(window).width();
        if (windowsize >= 1025) {

            $('.nav-menu> ul > li').click(function () {
                $(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function () {
                });
            })

        } else {
            //something else
        }

    });

});
```

Additionally you have the event listener only ever added once the user resizes the window, this is unlikely to happen most users don't really resize their windows especially on mobile. Remove the resize code or alternatively move the the menu toggle code outside of the resize function and it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav-menu> ul > li').click(function () {
        $(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function () {
        });
    })

});
```

Remember to include a menu button outside this list that toggles the menu so that the user is not stuck without navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this : using css display none to close the ul li.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).resize(function() {
        windowsize = $(window).width();
          if (windowsize >= 1025) {
            $('.nav-menu> ul > li').click(function(){

              $(this).css({'display':"none"});
              $(this).toggleClass("close"); //or
              $(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function(){

              });
            });
            }else {}
     });
    });
```

Comment: Not working for me. Something is wrong with my script. It's keep toggleing, even if I dont do anything.

Comment: what wrong any error? try to use toggleClass("close"); on the example adding.